# Variable used to store data from Excel file broken? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, variables, browser-automation, testcomplete

I am currently developing a Keyword driven framework using JavaScript / TestComplete and have an Excel file which contains a step number, Description, Keyword, Locator and Data.

I am currently reading the data from the Excel file (.xlsx) and storing the data (in this case the locator) in a variable..

I am storing the String Browsers.Item(btlExplorer,"",Browsers.pX64 in a variable called locator. When I then attempt this: locator.Run(https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#spf=1); I receive this error: JavaScript runtime error. TypeError. getLocator(...).Run is not a function.

This is my getLocator function:

```
function getLocator(x){

  var driver;
  var value;

  driver = DDT.ExcelDriver("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Automation Framework.xlsx", "Sheet1", false);

  while (! driver.EOF() && driver.Value(0) != x){

    DDT.CurrentDriver.Next();

  }

  value = driver.Value(3);

  Log.Message(value);
  DDT.CloseDriver(driver.Name);

  return value;
}
```

And here is the function I am running:

```
function openGoogle()
{ 
  //Launches the specified browser and opens the specified URL in it.
  getLocator(1).Run("https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#spf=1");
}
```

I am new to JavaScript, if you could give me any tips / advice on what is going wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value returned by the `getLocator` function is a string, you can work with it as a string and it does not have the `Run` method.

To get the actual object with the `Run` method, you need to evaluate the string in this way:

```
function openGoogle()
{ 
  //Launches the specified browser and opens the specified URL in it.
  let brwsr = eval(getLocator(1));
  brwsr.Run("https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#spf=1");
}
```